# How does a DNS server handle subdomains?

Tags: dns

Let’s say I visit a web page at NetCinema by requesting the url `www.NetCinema.com`. We know that the local DNS server will query NetCinema's authoritative DNS server to the the ip address of NetCinema and a cache record is added in the local DNS server as well.
Then, when I click a video link `http://video.netcinema.com/6Y7B23V`, how does my local DNS server treat this url? Will the DNS server return the cached record or since video prefix is a subdomain, the DNS server will again send a query to NetCinema's authoritative DNS server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each name has its own DNS records – really, *the whole point* of subdomains is that each of them can have different records (and point to different IP addresses) than the main domain. Because of that, each name is cached independently.

So when you're trying to look up 'video.netcinema.com', it has to be queried again at the authoritative servers. It doesn't matter whether you have 'www.netcinema.com' cached – that information doesn't allow you to guess anything about its sibling subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

From what I [and BlueHost](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/app/#/domains/subdomains) understand the SubDomain will have its own separate DNS Records

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).